# No such device = Grub Rescue 13.10

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

Noob here. I just installed 13.10 yesterday And it booted up for me several times and all was well. Then this morning when I went to boot I received a "No such device" error and a "grub rescue" command line prompt. I tried running the live disc and re-installing Ubuntu 13.10 However that was a fail. The same messages kept occurring. Then I tried to boot up in Windows 7. Also a fail. I then attempted to run a Windows 7 restore disc. You guessed it - Fail. This sucks. What do I do?

Comment: check your boot order in bios.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but did you end up upgrading grub at some point? This causes many people errors... And be more descriptive what grub rescue line comes up

Answer (score 0):

You can fix GRUB via the Ubuntu install disk.  You do not need to re-install Ubuntu.  When initially opening the Install disk there is an option to Repair Ubuntu.  Click through the various screens until you get to a menu that mentions repair (or re-instal grub).  Choose that menu option and the system will rebuild grub for you (including recognising Windows partition and adding a grub menu option for that).

Hope this helps